# How to disable eldoc for `eval-expression`?

Tags: elisp, eldoc

After a recent update `eldoc` is turned on by default, even for `emacs -Q`.
I don't appreciate the noise it generates when I'm using `eval-expression`.
How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable it globally:

```
(global-eldoc-mode -1)
```

Disable it locally - make sure that `eldoc-mode` is `nil` in all your buffers.

A less drastic solution would be to increase `eldoc-idle-delay`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: check buffer-local values of `eldoc-mode`.

Comment: Setting `eldoc-idle-delay` works, but how would I disable `eldoc-mode` for minibuffer?
I tried `minibuffer-setup-hook`, it didn't work.

Comment: wdym "disable eldoc-mode for minibuffer"? just kill the timer

Comment: Killing the timer doesn't work. Tested with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: `(global-eldoc-mode nil)` works with `emacs -Q`

Comment: No, it doesn't on today's build. Just `eval-expression`, type `(+` and the hint will appear in the modeline. All with `emacs -Q`

Comment: Problems with dev builds should be discussed on `emacs-devel` mailing list. SE is for long term knowledge.

Comment: It should be `(global-eldoc-mode -1)`: `nil` for minor modes used to mean "toggle" but nowadays it means "enable".

Comment: Thanks @Stefan - why was such a counter-intuitive change made?

Comment: Because "toggle" is virtually never the behavior that's needed when called non-interactively.  This change fixed latent bugs for all those people who had `(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook 'bar-mode)` in their .emacs.  A side-benefit is that we don't need any `turn-on-foo-mode` any more.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to control the behavior from the minibuffer when using `eval-expression`, use `eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook`.

For example, if you have eldoc on globally and want it off only in this one case, use:

```
(defun turn-off-eldoc () (eldoc-mode -1))
(add-hook 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook #'turn-off-eldoc)
```

This hook is new in Emacs 24.4.

Comment: The answer from @sds is exactly right if you do not want to use eldoc at all. However from your question it sounds like you are specifically interested in disabling eldoc when using `eval-expression`. Another option of course is to disable eldoc globally and then use hooks to selectively turn in on, e.g. `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'eldoc-mode)`